# Use HAProxy to capture piece of path as variable to use in Host header

Tags: haproxy

I'm trying to use HAProxy to rewrite a server name that lives in the original path to be in the Host header instead, and save that name for `use_backend` logic. For example, I want `proxy.my.host/server-1/some-request` to be rewritten to `server-1.internal/some-request`, and then to select `server-1`'s backend with `use_backend`.

```
frontend my_proxy
  ...
  # grab the server name from the request path
  http-request set-var(req.server_name) path,lower   # how do I trim /some-request from here?
  
  # strip /server-N from the path
  http-request replace-path ^(/server-[0-9]+) /

  # change the host header to server-N.internal
  http-request set-header Host var(req.server_name).internal

  # select the backend
  use_backend %[var(req.server_name)]

backend server-1
  ...
...
```

Is this generally the right approach for this sort of thing?